# Iterate and replace values through a numpy array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for creating a random dimension numpy array, iterate and replace values per 10 for example.

I tried :

```
# Import numpy library
import numpy as np

def Iter_Replace(x):
    print(x)
    for i in range(x):
        x[i] = 10
    print(x)
    

def main():
    x = np.array(([1,2,2], [1,4,3]))
    Iter_Replace(x)

main()
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: `range(x)` does not make sense if `x` is array.  What were you trying to do?

Comment: hello @hpaulj. Cyttorak understood my question. In fact I wanted to replace per 10 all the values of the arrays in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `numpy` function for this, `numpy.full` or `numpy.full_like`:

```
>>> x = np.array(([1,2,2], [1,4,3]))
>>> np.full(x.shape, 10)

array([[10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10]])
# OR,
>>> np.full_like(x, 10)

array([[10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

If you want to iterate you can either use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> def Iter_Replace(x):
        indices = product(*map(range, x.shape))
        for index in indices:
            x[tuple(index)] = 10
        return x
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,2], [1,4,3]])
>>> Iter_Replace(x)

array([[10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

Or, use `np.nditer`

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,2], [1,4,3]])

>>> for index in np.ndindex(x.shape):
        x[index] = 10
    
>>> x

array([[10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you got my question but the print returned :

[[1 2 2]
 [1 4 3]]

Comment: You need to assign it back to `x` and then print. `x = np.full_like(x, 10)`, `print(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors. There are missing parenthesis in the first line of `main`:

```
x = np.array(([1,2,2], [1,4,3]))
```

And you must replace `range(x)` by `range(len(x))` in the `Iter_Replace` function.